# Differential equation $x'' = -kx$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Initial condition  $x(0)=1$, $k>0$

\begin{eqnarray}
\lambda^2=-k
\end{eqnarray}
\begin{eqnarray}
\lambda=\pm\sqrt{-k}
\end{eqnarray}
I have no idea how to erase this $k$

what should be the next step?

Comment: The best way to solve an ODE is to know its answer. $$x(t) = c_1 \cos(-\sqrt{k} t) + c_2 \sin(-\sqrt{k} t)$$

Comment: Perhaps your DE textbook tells you what to do with complex values of $\lambda$.  Or perhaps you should use complex exponentials: $e^{\lambda t}$ with $\lambda$ a complex number.  With neither of these, you are stuck.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{eqnarray}
λ^{2}=-k
\end{eqnarray}\\
\lambda = \pm i\sqrt k\\ x=c_1 \cos \sqrt k x +c_2 \sin \sqrt k x\\ x(0)=1\implies  c_1=1\\x=  \cos \sqrt k x  +   c\sin \sqrt k x $$

Answer (score 1):

It's a linear differential equation :
$$x'' = -kx$$
$$x'' +kx=0$$
$$R^2-i^2k=0 \implies R= \pm i\sqrt k$$
$$x(t)=c_1 \cos( \sqrt k t)+c_2 \sin ( \sqrt k t)$$
Initial condition
$$x(0)=1 \implies c_1=1$$
$$\boxed {x(t)=\cos( \sqrt k t)+c_2 \sin ( \sqrt k t)}$$